# Is there a way to change the way python interprets code?

Tags: python

Is there a way to change the way python interprets what you enter? For example, swap the role of “==“ (boolean) and “=“ (variable assignment)?

Comment: Create your own programming language? I don't know any other way of achieving that!! (Btw I don't know why you asking thatz but I think you could use macros and refactor to automatically swap symbols, but the way python sees them is always same)

Comment: Such things done by source to source compiling (aka trans-compiling). It is pretty common  on Javascript ecosystem with tools like Babel to compile  ES6 or TypeScript into legacy Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can definitely change the meaning of operators in python. It is called as operator overloading.

Use Python magic methods or special functions for operator overloading

`

```
Binary Operators:  OPERATOR MAGIC METHOD 
+   __add__(self, other)
–   __sub__(self, other)
*   __mul__(self, other)
/   __truediv__(self, other)
//  __floordiv__(self, other)
%   __mod__(self, other)
**  __pow__(self, other)

Comparison Operators :

OPERATOR    MAGIC METHOD
<   __lt__(self, other)
>   __gt__(self, other)
<=  __le__(self, other)
>=  __ge__(self, other)
==  __eq__(self, other)
!=  __ne__(self, other)

Assignment Operators :

OPERATOR    MAGIC METHOD
-=  __isub__(self, other)
+=  __iadd__(self, other)
*=  __imul__(self, other)
/=  __idiv__(self, other)
//= __ifloordiv__(self, other)
%=  __imod__(self, other)
**= __ipow__(self, other)

Unary Operators :

OPERATOR    MAGIC METHOD
–   __neg__(self, other)
+   __pos__(self, other)
~   __invert__(self, other)`
```

these are the methods you can use to overload your operators.

Comment: I’m not quite sure I understand how to use the magic methods. Of course, it might be the python app I am using, but whenever I run the script, it gives me an error